# JQuery Jtable Change position of Add/Edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

Is there any way to change the position of jquery jtable edit or delete button? They appear at the last columns of the row i.e at the right most end.
Is there any way to bring them in the left i.e. at the beginning of the row?

Comment: Maybe you can include this https://github.com/nubuntu/jtable/blob/master/lib/extensions/jquery.jtable.buttonleft.js

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom icons anywhere you want

```
fields: {
            Name: {
                title: 'Name'
            },
            Email: {
                title: 'Email',
                key: true,
                list: true,
                display: function (data) {  // display text with Icon
                    var delete_icon = document.createElement('a');
                    delete_icon.className = 'btn'
                    delete_icon.setAttribute('href', '#');
                    delete_icon.setAttribute(
                       'onClick', 'YourFunctionName(' + your paramters+ ');'
                     );
                     return $(data.records.Email + '--'+ delete_icon);
                }
            },
            'DeleteIcon': {
                width: '1%',
                sorting: false,
                display: function(data) {
                        if (data.record) {
                            var delete_icon = document.createElement('a');
                            delete_icon.className = 'btn'
                            delete_icon.setAttribute('href', '#');
                            delete_icon.setAttribute(
                                'onClick', 'YourFunctionName(' + your paramters+ ');'
                            );
                            return $(delete_icon);
                        }
                }
            },
        },
```